# acralyzer dashboard not showing bug reports

Tags: android, crash-reports, android-logcat, acra, acralyzer

I followed this tutorial - https://www.toptal.com/android/automated-android-crash-reports-with-acra-and-cloudant to the latter.

I have the database of the app and the acralyzer created.
[image]

this is my configuration:

```
@ReportsCrashes(
    formUri = "https://ofektest.cloudant.com/acra-apptest/_design/acra-storage/_update/report",
    reportType = HttpSender.Type.JSON,
    httpMethod = HttpSender.Method.POST,
    formUriBasicAuthLogin = "***", // from the permissions API key generated
    formUriBasicAuthPassword = "***", // from the permissions API key generated
    customReportContent = {
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PACKAGE_NAME,
            ReportField.REPORT_ID,
            ReportField.BUILD,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE
    },
    mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
    resToastText = R.string.toast_crash
)

public class HealthCheckerApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);
    } 
}
```

In my main activity, I crash the app on purpose with a **null exception** with this code: just like the [example](https://github.com/TheMedo/acra_example)

```
    String crashString = null;
    crashString.length();
```

I see the `crash` Toast in the app, but when I go to my dashboard, I cant see any bugs/reports/anything!

[image]

How can I see the bugs? and crash reports?

**EDIT:** Here is my `logcat` after the crash:

```
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4165adb8)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA: ACRA caught a NullPointerException for com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker.ui.activities.HomeActivity.startService(HomeActivity.java:47)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker.ui.activities.HomeActivity$$ViewBinder$1.doClick(HomeActivity$$ViewBinder.java:24)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
06-23 18:47:06.493 24779-24779/com.ofekagmon.apps.healthchecker E/ACRA:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 18:47:08.603 24779-25247/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24779 SIG: 9
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Even I can see crash report as a record created in database. But I cannot see anything in report on dashboard. Did you solve this. If yes please can you share your findings? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any record present in `acra-apptest`?. If yes then in Acralyzer do F12 and check the network request.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your logcat. ACRA will log what it is doing, including details of posting the crash to your report server. Verify that it is able to send.

Comment: I do see the ACRA logging, and still my Acralyzer dashboard is empty. see edited question with logcat

Comment: So ACRA has caught the crash. There will be more ACRA log showing what ACRA does with it. Ie sending to your server. That is the log that is interesting.